# How to Display Alarm is set for tomorrow and I'll wake you up later

Tags: java, interface

I'm having a problem compiling my codes right now. I don't know what is the problem but please help me.
This is the instructions I have to follow.

[image: Procedures]

This is my codes that I have finished so far.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.time.LocalTime;

public class Monday extends Weekday{

    private String time;
    
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        Monday m = new Monday();
    
        String alarmer;
        System.out.print("Enter time for alarm in this format (HH:MM): ");
        alarmer = s.nextLine();
        
        m.setAlarm(alarmer);
        m.showAlarm();
    }
    
    public void setAlarm(String time) {
        this.time = time;
        LocalTime alarm = LocalTime.parse(time);
        LocalTime now = LocalTime.now();
         
        if (alarm.isBefore(now)) {
            System.out.println("I'll wake you up later!");
        }
         
        else {
            System.out.println("Alarm is set for tomorrow!");
        }
    }
     public String showAlarm() {
        return time;
    }
     
}
```

The problem is whenever I compile it, it will always result to this.

[image: output]

and this is the expected result/output.

[image: Sample output]

Comment: "_Enter time for alarm in this format (HH:MM)_", but you enter `3:00`, which is not the correct format that `LocalTime.parse()` seems to accept. Make sure to enter the correct time format.

Comment: The time format is (HH:MM) so your input should be 03:00

Answer (score 0):

Your problem occurs in parsing string to localtime. Read this : https://howtodoinjava.com/java/date-time/java-localtime/

Answer (score 0):

I got your solution for you but I also changed your code a bit. You have an extension class. So what you do in **Monday** class, you should do in **Weekday** class so you don't have to repeat it for every single day.

**Your alarm interface**

```
public interface Alarm {

    void setAlarm(String time);
    String showAlarm(); 
}
```

**Your Monday class**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Monday extends Weekday{

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        new Monday();
    }
    
    public Monday()
    {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter time for alarm in this format (HH:MM): ");
        setAlarm(scanner.nextLine());
    }         
}
```

**At last, your Weekday class**

```
import java.text.MessageFormat;
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.DateTimeParseException;

public class Weekday implements Alarm {

    private final String mTimeFormat = "HH:mm";
    private String mTime; // I don't know why you need this. Return value is never used
    
    @Override
    public void setAlarm(String time) {     
        
        try
        {
            this.mTime = time;
            DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(mTimeFormat);
            LocalTime alarm = LocalTime.parse(time, formatter);     
            LocalTime now = LocalTime.now();
            
            if (alarm.isBefore(now)) {
                System.out.println("I'll wake you up later!");
            }else {
                System.out.println("Alarm is set for tomorrow!");
            }
        }
        catch(DateTimeParseException ex)
        {
            System.err.println(MessageFormat.format("Wrong time format with {0}. Excepted time format {1}", time, mTimeFormat));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String showAlarm() {
        return mTime;
    }
}
```

See the line `DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(mTimeFormat);`
This is where you format your input. You can handle various types of date formats in here.